# Can not save token to personal_access_tokens table in laravel

Tags: laravel

My login code in Laravel as the following

```
            if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }
            $infoUser = Auth::guard('api')->user();
            $personAccessToken = [
                'tokenable_type' => "App\Models\User",
                'tokenable_id' => $infoUser->id,
                'name' => $infoUser->name,
                'token' => $token,
            ];
            PersonalAccessToken::updateOrCreate(['tokenable_id' => $infoUser->id], $personAccessToken);
```

when I test API on postman it shows the error "*SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'token' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens`* "
.
Token value is generated from this function `auth('api')->attempt($credentials)`.

Token column in `personal_access_tokens` table is created by Laravel with string length 64 and it's unique. If I change to the text, this field can not set unique.
How can I resolve this problem?
Could everyone help me?

Comment: You should create a new migration to modify the table as 255 char string for this field.

Comment: @SachinKumar This  token value's length is 330 characters. 255 char isn't enough.

Comment: Which package are you using? I was thinking that you are using the passport.

Comment: @SachinKumar: This package "Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class"

Comment: use laravel sanctum and then just call after the user validation in api auth $user->createToken($request->deviceName)->plainTextToken;

Comment: according to this doc https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/ they did not create a table for token. are you using this package standalone or with some other package?